# how to remove all text except one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to remove all text except one in javascript

the idea is do something like

```
//retrieve something like "cnode_72 cnode_1 layout_1  ui-datepicker-week-end "
// "ui-datepicker-week-end" is not necessary always present
var classes= jQuery("someelement").attr("class"); 

classes = classes.replace(/(?!ui-datepicker-week-end)/,'');
```

the expected ouput is :

```
ui-datepicker-week-end
```

Comment: do you mean just keep the last class, or what?

Comment: I believe more example of what you want to do would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Javascript (as per question)**

Erm... might be missing something here, but how about:

```
classes = "ui-datepicker-week-end";
```

If that text isn't in the original string, and thus you don't want to add it if it isn't already there then try this:

```
if(classes.indexOf("ui-datepicker-week-end") == -1)
    classes = "";
else
    classes = "ui-datepicker-week-end";
```

---

**JQuery (as per request in comments)**

If by some bizarre reason you are using the `jQuery("...").attr("class")` but didn't bother mentioning that, then try this:

```
jQuery("...").removeAttr("class").addClass("ui-datepicker-week-end");
```

or with the condition:

```
if(jQuery("...").hasClass("ui-datepicker-week-end"))
    jQuery("...").removeAttr("class").addClass("ui-datepicker-week-end");
else
    jQuery("...").removeAttr("class");
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sb3xgs1b/)

Comment: was just commenting the same thing. I'm not sure the question is really accurate though, it seems too simple.

Comment: It seems the optimal :)

Comment: What if `ui-datepicker-week-end` isn't there in original string?

Comment: the var classes = "...", was just as example to show you  the content, i'm getting that information from jQuery("...").attr("class"), that class "ui-datepicker-week-end" is not always present

Comment: @anubhava The expected behavior is not defined. So I think is as fair this as having an exception in the case of `match`.

Comment: @Joyal logically that doesn't change anything, it simply changes the assignment statements.